# Unable to run fsk (to solve boot problem)

Tags: boot

After updating Xubuntu 18.04 I am suddenly unable to boot my dual-boot PC.

The error message I get when I try to boot in recovery mode is:

*/dev/sda5: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsk MANUALLY
...
fsk exited with status code 4
done.
Failure: File system check of the root filesystem failed
The root filesystem on /dev/sda5 requires a manual fsck
BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs) _*

I have unsuccessfully attempted to run fsk at the prompt as shown below.

*(initramfs) fsk /dev/sda5
sh: fsk: not found*

I got the same result trying to run fsk after switching to the /sbin directory.

*(initramfs) cd sbin
(initramfs) fsk /dev/sda5
sh: fsk: not found*

Another thing that I tried was to boot using a live USB drive.  However this failed to work.  As the PC boots using the live USB drive, it hangs up.  Specifically, when the solid colored Xubuntu background page appears during boot, there is a spinning icon; this is where the system hangs.

I do not know what to try next.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: You are the victim of a typo, the command is `fsck`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  When I used "fsck" the filecheck began.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition....

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- or at the initramfs prompt...
- at the # or initramfs prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda5` # fsck sda5
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: I know that is late but '''sudo fsck -f''' didn't work for me, always says abortion, why?

Comment: @Marinela You didn't use the entire command. What version Ubuntu? I'll update my answer for you.